En hackerrank estoy haciendo un codigo y me arroja error en la entrada. La entrada las quiere en una misma celda
CAPACIDAD_CALORIFICA_AGUA = 4.186
masa_agua = float(input())
cambio_temperatura = float(input())
cantidad_calor = masa_agua * CAPACIDAD_CALORIFICA_AGUA * cambio_temperatura
conversion_Joules_a_Kw_h = cantidad_calor / 3600000
print("Se necesitan", cantidad_calor, "Joules", "o", conversion_Joules_a_Kw_h, "Kw/h")
file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/2.png

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No se entiende cual es tu problema.. ahi solo hay un pedazo de codigo...

¿Quieres decir que debes ingresar ambos valores en un solo input()?

claro exactamente
